# Javascript regular exp: referring to a nested group

Tags: javascript, regex

So I've got this RegExp to validate some input like this:

```
1   12919840    T   C
1   35332717    C   A
1   55148456    G   T
1   70504789    C   T
1   167059520   A   T
1   182496864   A   T
1   197073351   C   T
1   216373211   G   T
```

The exp i came up with is:

```
/^([0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG][\s|\n]+)*[0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG][\s|\n]*$/g
```

This worked in something like

```
/^([0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG][\s|\n]+)*[0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG][\s|\n]*$/g.test("1 12919840 T C\n1 35332717 C A"); //this returns true
```

But when trying use group reference to make it shorter it doesn't work anymore

```
/^(([0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG])[\s|\n]+)*\2[\s|\n]*$/g.test("1 12919840 T C\n1 35332717 C A"); //this returns false
```

I'm using `\2` here since from my research the numbering of the groups starts from the left most parenthesis. what did I miss? thx!

Comment: `\2` represents the inner group and `\1` represents the inner + outer group.

Comment: so `\2` means `([0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG])` and `\1` represents `(([0-9]\s+[0-9]+\s+[ATCG]\s+[ATCG])[\s|\n]+)`

Comment: You can't make them shorter using back references, because they reference the matched results of a previous expression, not the used expression itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer addresses your `what did I miss?` question. For a workaround, see the [answer by @Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24624626/1078583).

**A Capture Group is Not a Subroutine**

What you're missing is that a capture group is not a subroutine.

When you say `\1`, you are referring to the exact characters that were captured by the parentheses of Group 1. For instance, `(\d)\1` would match `11` or `22`, but not `12`.

**Regex Subroutines**

In Perl and `PCRE`, you can refer to a subexpression by using `(?1)`. For instance, `(\d)(?1)` would match `11` as well as `12`.

This is also available in the `regex` module for Python. Sadly, this is not available in JavaScript, which you seem to be using.

Since you're working with `DNA`, if you have a chance, I'd suggest working in a life-embracing language such as Python (JS has poor regex abilities, though the `XregeExp` library fills some holes.)

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot, I'm using this in a form validation, so JavaScript is the most straightforward choice right now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your expression is that back references match whatever was matched by a previous memory capture; the expression that generated the memory capture itself can't be referenced in this manner.

That said, you can still shorten the expression by using a multiplier on your expression:

```
var re = /((?:^\d+\s+\d+\s+[TCGA]\s+[TCGA][\s\r\n]*){2})/gm,
    m;
```

The expression matches the same thing twice, with an optional set of spaces in between. To iterate over all matches:

```
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  console.log('match' + m[1]);
}
```